# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to run this code but it's giving "_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2" " this error.
But If I run the same code without ebook function, it's working fine. As I'm new to coding, any help will be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

mylabel0= Label(root, text="        ")
mylabel0.grid(row=0, column=0)

def ebook():
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from gtts import gTTS
    import pdfplumber

    book = tk.Tk()
    book.minsize(width=150, height=200)
    book.maxsize(width=300, height=420)

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(book, width=300, height=420, bg='azure3', relief='raised')
    canvas1.grid()

    label1 = tk.Label(book, text="PDF Audio Store", bg='azure3')
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', 16))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 20, window=label1)

    final = ""

    def get_pdf():
        global final
        global pdf_checker

        try:
            import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

            if (str(import_file_path).endswith(".pdf")):
                pdf = pdfplumber.open(import_file_path)
                pdf_checker = pdf

                n = len(pdf.pages)

                for page in range(n):
                    data = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
                    final = final + "\n" + data

                messagebox.showinfo("Information", "PDF is imported")
            else:
                raise Exception("Provide .pdf file only")

        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "{}".format(e))

        else:
            print("Continue to conversion")

    brows_pdf = tk.Button(text="PDF entry", command=get_pdf, bg='royalblue', fg="white", font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                          border=0,
                          activebackground="green")
```

It's giving error in this() area specifically, create_window.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZnad.png)

```
    canvas1.create_window(150, 60, window=brows_pdf)

    def convert_audio():
        global final
        global pdf_checker

        try:
            print("File Information")
            print(pdf_checker)
            export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".mp3")
            final_file = gTTS(text=final, lang="en")
            final_file.save(export_file_path)

            messagebox.showinfo("Information", "Audio file generated")
        except NameError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Import PDF first")

    audio_button = tk.Button(text="Convert to Audio", command=convert_audio, bg='royalblue', fg="white",
                             font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                             border=0,
                             activebackground="green")
    canvas1.create_window(150, 100, window=audio_button)

    book.mainloop()

button_ebook= Button(root, text="E-Book", font=30, padx=25, pady=25, command=ebook, fg="black", bg="white", borderwidth=1)
button_ebook.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That means you've either destroyed the button, or you created the button in a different instance of `Tk`. You shouldn't be creating more than one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Then what I can do to run it? I changed it from 'Tk' to 'Toplevel' but still giving error.

Comment: it would be easier to tell if you provided a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you can't use a button in one window that is a descendant of another window.

The first problem is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. Buttons created in one instance are not available in the other. In this case, your button is in the original instance of `Tk` but your canvas is in the other.

The second problem is similar. Even when replacing the second instance of `Tk`, the button is in the root window and thus can't be used as a child of the canvas which is in the second window.

The solution is to use `Toplevel` for the second window, and to make sure the button is a descendant of the second window and/or the canvas.